# 2D heat equation in both steady state and Transient state using iterative solvers

Tags: finite-difference, iterative-method

While solving a 2D heat equation in both steady-state and Transient state using iterative solvers like Jacobi, Gauss seidel, SOR. Should the answers, I mean the converged results of Temperature contour on the 2D surface be the same?

As transient state is solved using certain time steps to get to steady-state. So does that mean my result after convergence in transient state should be equal to what I got in Steady-state?

Comment: The English style of this question should be improved, it is hard to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

If you solve the transient heat equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - k\nabla^2u = 0$$

for a very long time, and you then solve the Poisson equation

$$-k\nabla^2u = 0$$

with the same boundary conditions, **you should get roughly the same result**.
But we have to define what a "very long" time actually is.

You can write the solution of the time-dependent problem as

$$u(t) = \sum_ke^{-k\lambda_nt}\langle \phi_n, u(0)\rangle\phi_n + u(\infty)$$

where $\phi_n$, $\lambda_n$ are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplace operator on the domain, $u(0)$ is the initial value, and $u(\infty)$ is the steady-state value.
To 0th order, you only care about the smallest eigenmode because all others will decay much faster.
If $R$ is the radius of the largest circle that you can inscribe inside the domain, then

$$\lambda_1 \ge \pi^2 / R^2.$$

(See [these notes](https://www.math.uci.edu/~zlu/publications/2006-2010/28.pdf), it's a consequence of the Cheeger inequality.)
So if $\pi^2 kt / R^2$ is greater than, say, 5 or 10 you should be pretty close to steady state.

Now, you mentioned the Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel, and SOR methods.
These iterative methods do converge to the actual solution of the linear system eventually.
**But they are notoriously slow** on their own, **and they converge slowest for the smallest eigenmode** $\phi_1$, which is the one that matters the most when you're looking at relaxation to steady state.
So if you find that your numerical solution for $u(t)$ is very different from $u(\infty)$ even for large $t$, it might actually be a consequence of using a slowly-converging iterative method.
In that case I'd look at using a sparse direct solver.